# Material Ui & Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Did anyone know how I store my material Ui selector selection (selected data)  in redux by using dispatch.

Eg : I want to select data from material Ui selector and then store it in redux . But I don't know how I can store in it without button.  Usually we apply dispatch type and payload in button on submit but in selector how can I do .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to import dispatch and add action to reducer

```js
<Select onChange={(e) => dispatch({action: 'some_action', payload: e.target.value })} ... >
```